# Java class to run CompletableFuture<T> instances in batches

Tags: java, asynchronous

This is a utility class for running `CompletableFuture<T>`s in batches (e.g. to avoid using too much bandwidth making HTTP requests). It seems to work, but I'm a little iffy on the use of my `CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper` class— I need it so that `wrappedFuture` can remove itself from `running` after it completes. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this? Other code suggestions are also appreciated.

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

/**
 * Run {@link CompletableFuture}s in batches.
 *
 * @param <T> The type of the {@link CompletableFuture}.
 */
public final class JobsQueue<T> {

    private final Queue<Supplier<CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper>> waiting = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final Set<CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper> running = new HashSet<>();
    private final Queue<T> output = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final int maxJobsRunningAtOnce;

    /**
     * Initialize a new {@link JobsQueue} instance.
     *
     * @param maxJobsRunningAtOnce The maxmimum number of {@link CompletableFuture}s that will run simultaneously.
     */
    public JobsQueue(int maxJobsRunningAtOnce) {
        this.maxJobsRunningAtOnce = maxJobsRunningAtOnce;
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue a future.
     *
     * @param completableFutureSupplier Supplier for the future to be run.
     */
    public void add(Supplier<CompletableFuture<T>> completableFutureSupplier) {
        Supplier<CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper> wrappedSupplier = () -> {
            CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper wrapper = new CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper(null);
            CompletableFuture<T> originalFuture = completableFutureSupplier.get();
            CompletableFuture<Void> wrappedFuture = originalFuture.thenAccept(result -> {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        this.output.add(result);
                    }

                    this.running.remove(wrapper);
                    if (!this.waiting.isEmpty()) {
                        this.running.add(this.waiting.remove().get());
                    }
                }
            });
            wrapper.future = wrappedFuture;
            return wrapper;
        };
        synchronized (this) {
            if (this.running.size() < this.maxJobsRunningAtOnce) {
                this.running.add(wrappedSupplier.get());
            } else {
                this.waiting.add(wrappedSupplier);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wait for all running and waiting futures to complete before returning.
     */
    public void joinAll() {
        // not only must we join all futures in running, we must wait for those in waiting to trickle out as well
        while (true) {
            final boolean breakFlag;
            synchronized (this.waiting) {
                breakFlag = this.waiting.isEmpty();
            }

            final List<CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper> wrappers;
            synchronized (this.running) {
                wrappers = new ArrayList<>(this.running);
            }

            for (CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper wrapper : wrappers) {
                assert wrapper.future != null;
                wrapper.future.join();
            }

            if (breakFlag) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the results of all the completed futures so far.
     * Empties the results queue.
     *
     * @return a list of all the results of the completed futures.
     * If <code>T</code> is {@link Void}, returns an empty list.
     */
    public @NotNull List<T> getAll() {
        synchronized (this.output) {
            List<T> out = new ArrayList<>(this.output);
            this.output.clear();
            return out;
        }
    }

    private static class CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper {
        @Nullable CompletableFuture<Void> future;

        CompletableFutureReferenceWrapper(@Nullable CompletableFuture<Void> future) {
            this.future = future;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, the main idea is to control the number of parallel executions using `maxJobsRunningAtOnce`?

This is a violation of [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) as `JobsQueue` acts like both queue **and** executor.

If to separate the queue from the executor, you could simply use something like `running.forEach(CompletableFuture::join)` and control the parallel thread by an external executor.

Ok, let's forget about the initial design.

You do use an explicit synchronization on both `waiting` and `running` collections. The first one is already `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and it's safe to check its size. Additionally, you could avoid the second `synchronized` block by making `running` as thread-safe also, for example as `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`

By the way, `output` is declared as `ArrayDeque` but in the end, is used just to copy the values to the plain array list. Plain `ArrayList` would do the same trick.

Comment: I disagree about the SRP violation. Perhaps I should use a different name, like "BatchRunner." The rest is helpful, thanks.